# Empty output PySimpleGUI. execute_command_subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

I'm trying to develop a program that will execute commands sequentially and at the same time will not freeze during the execution of one of them (each command can take a long time, because it starts rendering in blender).

I tried to use the example from the cookbook, but in my case, only None is returned. With what it can be connected?
Cookbook program:
https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Script_Launcher_Realtime_Output.py

```
cmd_list = values['-IN-'].split(' ')
sp = sg.execute_command_subprocess(cmd_list[0], *cmd_list[1:], pipe_output=True, wait=False)
results = sg.execute_get_results(sp, timeout=1)
print(results[0])
```

This is how my execution command looks like (at the beginning is a whole string):

```
['"C:\\Program', 'Files\\Blender', 'Foundation\\Blender', '3.4\\blender.exe"', '-b', 
'"C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\blendertest\\Astor_Blue.blend"', '-o', 
'"C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\blendertest\\out\\Astor_Blue\\Astor_Blue.####"', '-s', '50', '-e', '52', '-t', '6', '-a']
```

and through the console/bat file it works fine. But as soon as I try to run it from my program or the program presented in the Cookbook - only None is returned.
At the same time, if I print only:
`"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.4\blender.exe"`
in program from Cookbook blender runs great.

What I do wrong? All I need is for the command to run and at the same time the window does not freeze for the duration of its execution

That my parts of code:

```
sg.Multiline(size=(100, 15), echo_stdout_stderr=True, reroute_stdout=True, autoscroll=True),
```

```
sp = sg.execute_command_subprocess(cmd_list[0], *cmd_list[1:], pipe_output=True, wait=False)
results = sg.execute_get_results(sp, timeout=1)
print(results[0])
```

All paths with "" and open blender.exe with this code works fine.

Test code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Multiline(size=(110, 30), echo_stdout_stderr=True, reroute_stdout=True, autoscroll=True, background_color='black', text_color='white', key='-MLINE-')],
    [sg.T('Promt> '), sg.Input(key='-IN-', focus=True, do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Button('Run', bind_return_key=True), sg.Button('Exit')]]

window = sg.Window('Realtime Shell Command Output', layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == 'Run':
        cmd_list = ['"C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.4\\blender.exe"', '-b',
                    '"C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\blendertest\\Astor_Blue.blend"', '-o',
                    '"C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\blendertest\\out\\Astor_Blue\\Astor_Blue.####"', '-s',
                    '50', '-e', '52', '-t', '6', '-a']
        print(cmd_list)
        sp = sg.execute_command_subprocess(cmd_list[0], *cmd_list[1:], pipe_output=True, wait=False)
        results = sg.execute_get_results(sp, timeout=1)
        print(results)

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running your command with your data in this format:

```
   ['"C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.4\\blender.exe"', '-b', 
    '"C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\blendertest\\Astor_Blue.blend"', '-o', 
    '"C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\blendertest\\out\\Astor_Blue\\Astor_Blue.####"', '-s',
    '50', '-e', '52', '-t', '6', '-a']
```

Your first element in your list must be the full path and executable file name you want to run.

Comment: Yep, try it too and again get None
Add my test code to question